# Gui Java Eventos de teclado

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 JPanel pb = new JPanel();
    JLabel b = new JLabel("Buscar por ...");
    JTextField bt = new JTextField(10);
    JButton bb = new JButton("Lupa");

    // bb.setBackground(color);
    bb.addActionListener(new Busquedad());
    bb.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            //Busquedad
        }

    });
```

La clase Busquedad recoge el texto escrito en un JTextField y realiza una búsqueda en la base de datos.

Mi problema es que quiero que se pueda ejecutar eso si clickeo el boton o si utilizo tab + enter , es decir , que al utilizar el teclado realice la búsqueda igual que si hiciese click

Answer (score 2):

Para eso debes agregar un evento a tu JTextField de la siguiente manera:

```
bt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HOLA");
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            //BUSQUEDA
        }
    }
});
```

Esto hace que luego de ingresar el parámetro de búsqueda oprimas la tecla enter, se disparará el evento